# Get node data from entity reference field

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I have an entity reference field to a content type blog. I referenced a specific blog, but when I render that field in twig using `{{ content.field_blog }}`. I want to get the autor name and time when that blog was created - not the blog's name by default. Field is in paragraph. 
I would like to do this using twig, so without any preprocesses.

How can I do that?

Comment: View mode of the referenced entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the author like this:

```
{{ paragraph.field_blog.entity.Owner.name.value }}
```

and the creation:

```
{{ paragraph.field_blog.entity.createdtime|format_date('medium') }}
```

Comment: I tried that, it's not rendering anything :/ On createdtime it throws exception "the timestamp must be numeric"...

Comment: Try paragraph instead of content

Comment: It works great @Jdrupal, thank you!

Comment: Quick question, it renders for all three fields even tho one field is not referenced to, do  you know why is that and how can i remove that line?

Comment: I think that I  have to see some code to help you

Comment: I solved my problem

Comment: I solved my problem with : {% if paragraph.field_blog is not empty %}
        {{ paragraph.field_blog.entity.Owner.name.value }} / {{ paragraph.field_blog.entity.createdtime|format_date('medium') }}
      {% endif %}

Comment: Cool, glad it helped :)